# Incorrect crop of tikzpicture in standalone when using komaoptions

Tags: tikz-pgf, koma-script, standalone, crop, multiple-files

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[
  tikz,
  border=0cm,
  class=scrbook,
]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pagecolor{lightgray}
% \KOMAoptions are actually included via a shared file
\KOMAoptions{
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=10pt,
  % INCORRECT CROP APPEARS WITH ANY OF FOLLOWING OPTIONS
  BCOR=10mm,
  % twoside,
  % DIV=14,
  % headinclude=false,
}
% \recalctypearea % THIS CAN ALSO BE RESPONSIBLE FOR AN INCORRECT CROP
\usepackage{layouts}
\begin{document}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
      \draw[rectangle, use as bounding box] (-4,-8.5) |- (8,6.3) |- cycle;
      \node[text width=8cm] at (0,0) {\pagevalues};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see the document is not properly cropped. Commenting `BCOR` will result in a correct crop.

What can I do to get a properly cropped picture?

Moving away from the package `standalone` would mean a rather large change of my actual document and organization of my latex project (see for more details [Luatex v0.95+standalone: \RequirePackage{luatex85} cannot be used in outsourced tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352928/luatex-v0-95standalone-requirepackageluatex85-cannot-be-used-in-outsourced)).
I probably should also note that I want to use values such as \textwidth in the tikzpicture to automatically place things according to the available textarea.

Comment: And why do you use BCOR in a standalone document? It only makes life harder. Separate your preamble code in "code needed also by standalone" and "code only for real document".

Comment: I think BCOR reduces the \textwidth and that's a parameter I want to use in my tikz picture to facilitate the maximum possible horizontal space. I already have a preamble in  my main.tex and a shared_preamble_part.tex which only contains items which are needed by both.

Comment: Setting `BCOR` results in a recalculation of the page layout similar to `\recalctypearea`.  Set the options regarding the `typearea` calculations as class options: `\documentclass[...,class=scrbook,paper=a4,fontsize=10pt,BCOR=100]{standalone}`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that does resolve the issue. Any chance to share these values between several standalone and the main tex file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beside using class options you can also reset the layout values to one expected by standalone after using the KOMA-keys:

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[
  tikz,
  border=0cm,
  class=scrbook,
]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\pagecolor{lightgray}
\KOMAoptions{
  paper=a4,
  fontsize=10pt,
   BCOR=10mm,
  % twoside,
  % DIV=14,
  % headinclude=false,
}
\makeatletter
\ifsa@crop
\pagestyle{empty}
\hoffset=-72.27pt
\voffset=-72.27pt
\topmargin=0pt
\headheight=0pt
\headsep=0pt
\marginparsep=0pt
\marginparwidth=0pt
\footskip=0pt
\marginparpush=0pt
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\evensidemargin=0pt
\topskip=0pt
\fi
\makeatother
\usepackage{layouts}
\begin{document}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
      \draw[rectangle, use as bounding box] (-4,-8.5) |- (8,6.3) |- cycle;
      \node[text width=8cm] at (0,0) {\pagevalues};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I do not understand what values are expected by `standalone`. Do I have to modify values such as `\hoffset=-72.27pt` when I change KOMAoptions?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I copied the values from standalone in my answer and it compiles fine.

Comment: I had a look into standalone.cls and I have found the values you've copied. I think this should do the trick as you've said. A minor issue is in your answer: there is a missing `\makeatother`. With this it also compiles fine for me.